# Does anyone beside me just NOT get ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been fiddling with ASP.NET MVC since the CTP, and I like a lot of things they did, but there are things I just don't get.

For example, I downloaded beta1, and I'm putting together a little personal site/resume/blog with it. Here is a snippet from the ViewSinglePost view:

```
 <%
        // Display the "Next and Previous" links
        if (ViewData.Model.PreviousPost != null || ViewData.Model.NextPost != null)
        {
            %> <div> <%

            if (ViewData.Model.PreviousPost != null)
            {
                %> <span style="float: left;"> <%
                    Response.Write(Html.ActionLink("<< " + ViewData.Model.PreviousPost.Subject, "view", new { id = ViewData.Model.PreviousPost.Id }));
                %> </span> <%
            }

            if (ViewData.Model.NextPost != null)
            {
                %> <span style="float: right;"> <%
                    Response.Write(Html.ActionLink(ViewData.Model.NextPost.Subject + " >>", "view", new { id = ViewData.Model.NextPost.Id }));
                %> </span> <%
            }
            %>
                   <div style="clear: both;" />
               </div> <%
        }
    %>
```

Disgusting! **(Also note that the HTML there is temporary placeholder HTML, I'll make an actual design once the functionality is working)**.

Am I doing something wrong? Because I spent many dark days in classic ASP, and this tag soup reminds me strongly of it.

Everyone preaches how you can do cleaner HTML. Guess, what? 1% of all people look at the outputted HTML. To me, I don't care if Webforms messes up my indentation in the rendered HTML, as long as I have code that is easy to maintain...This is not!

So, convert me, a die hard webforms guy, why I should give up my nicely formed ASPX pages for this?

**Edit:** Bolded the "temp Html/css" line so people would stfu about it.

Comment: man that is some ugly markup!

Comment: This is like a bad dream. MS made ASP.NET worse?

Comment: You include CSS markup with your HTML?

Comment: i might not feel so strongly about ASP.NET MVC if they had named it McWebFrame.NET instead of MVC.

Comment: Wow... That is some ugly code. You should stop writing code that is so very ugly. I must confess, i don't understand why ASP.NET MVC would inspire such ugliness from you; perhaps you should write the markup first, and then add the logic to it?

Comment: It's hard to not think back to ASP when you look at it ... **shudders**

Comment: SHog9, I always start development at the backend, and work to the frontend. Read the bolded text.

Comment: Your formatting sucks. THat's not a problem inherent to MVC, it's a sign of a bad HTML programmer. Too much time spent in the observer pattern, me thinks. A little more than drag, drop, click is required here.

Comment: The line you bolded is not what people are complaining about. What they are complaining about is the excessive quantity of code-noise. Code-noise should be contained to the controllers, and excised from the views. Views are about removing the code where possible and leaving only markup.

Comment: Agreed, tell me how to remove the code noise. Tvannsons refractoring skipped a major thing (the first if block), and used ternaries...Something I hate, otherwise its the same exact logic.

Comment: Actually, he edited, so he has the enclosing if block now. In my opinion while his code is more compact, its still the same amount of logic, and I dislike it in the view.

Comment: @Jonathan - we need to just keep quiet and let everyone applaud the emperor's new clothes.  i've been applying the actual MVC pattern to webforms for years to good effect.  they've relabeled a bunch of stuff (some good, some not so good) as MVC.NET and the lemmings are eating it up.

Comment: @Jonathan - actually, a whole lot of people have been correctly applying the design pattern to good effect...

it's funny that the thing that MSFT calls MVC doesn't really follow the pattern.

Comment: That's because Rails isn't MVC either, and ASP.NET MVC is "C# on Rails".

Comment: @mson - Wasn't the reason for his post was to get supporting ideas for why to use MVC? Is the fact that people are highlighting why they like it and how it is useful meet the needs for his post? What answers did you expect/prefer to see?

Comment: That was the idea of my post, but when the answer was "Well, your code, just written more compact", it disappointed me.

Comment: ALSO - You guys might not want to be so offended that we "lemmings" are "eating this up". This is my first venture into the Model-View-Controller pattern so _I_don't_know_ what it should look like, but for what it is, I like this "effort" at MVC. Why not help us understand what we are missing?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are admitting that your code is a work in progress, correct? Maybe once it reaches it's final form you won't be so disappointed?

Comment: @hboss - your confusion about mvc is part of my frustration (at MSFT, not you).  they have mislabeled their offering.  if it were called C# on Rails, i wouldn't object.  their labeling is going to further confuse people...

there are a lot of articles that explain mvc better than i can

Comment: The shooting of the messenger here is disappointing.  I posted a similar topic on Joel's site: http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.716045.15

Comment: Never mind MVC, calling Winforms "easy to maintain" is silly. It's easy to maintain as long as you don't need any degree of control over the output. Which means it works fine as long as your users only use MS-sanctioned web browsers.

Comment: jalf, that isn't true at all. Our sites work on all browsers, and it only takes minimal work. We pretty much just use repeaters, which allows us for flexible markup without loading our view up with logic.

Comment: Cross browser compatibility is framework/language/IDE independent

Comment: I'm not sure how much people are using them, but the ability to use the Html.RenderPartial(<UserControl>) is a pretty handy way of still creating controls with their logic contained within. You actually even still use normal page controls that don't require the page level form!

Comment: @Jonathan: sorry if i contributed to the name-calling that seems to have infected this question - the point i was trying to make is: you're attacking this from the wrong angle; MVC works best when you work with each layer separately (continued)

Comment: ...design model(s) that it logically represents the data you're working with (if necessary, a facade over the physical representation rather than letting that leak through); design the viewS such that they match the results you wish to display, populating each with data from the model (continued)

Comment: ... (rather than the ASP / WebForms method of one representation mutated as needed); and design the controller to choose the appropriate view based on what the user has elected to display. The issues you're seeing can be avoided by moving controller logic from the view into the controller.

Comment: Shog, the model contains a Previous and next post link, most of the logic is in the model, the controller just passes this data to the view. I still need to determine if I will create the hyperlink or not in the view. I have no idea how why you think that is not UI logic.

Comment: It is a determination that will need to be made at one point or another and seems like, imo, that it would be best left up to the person doing the UI. The model in this instance could be designed better, but having a branch of logic about UI in the UI seems natural to me. UI and Markup in... (cont.)

Comment: (continued from above)...the code behind never felt correct.

Comment: This question comes up too often when I search for something.

Comment: I agree that the default view engine for ASP.NET MVC looks very ugly; however, there are alternatives available that make working with the View code a great experience!

I would HIGHLY recommend checking out the SparkViewEngine(http://sparkviewengine.com/)

Comment: WebForms is an ugly hack to try and make the web feel more like WinForms and is a crutch for developers that are too lazy to learn the right way to do it. I downvoted the question because you simply marked the answer as the one that agreed with you.

Comment: To make you happy, I [rewrote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390693/does-anyone-beside-me-just-not-get-asp-net-mvc/6856653#6856653) your sample with [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx).

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? - Yes. But it isn't your fault. You need to write some nice HTML and then add the output from the Model to it. You don't need Response.Write ever! The idea behind the MVC framework is that it makes things much cleaner than .aspx, whereas your example looks more like Classic ASP.

Comment: see also "Does anyone beside me just NOT get ASP.NET WebForms?"

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Compared to Web Forms, MVC is simultaneously a lower-level approach to HTML generation with greater control over the page output *and* a higher-level, more architecturally-driven approach. Let me capture Web Forms and MVC and show why I think that the comparison favors Web Forms in many situations - as long as you don't fall into some classic Web Forms traps.

**Web Forms**

In the Web Forms model, your pages correspond directly to the page request from the browser. Thus, if you are directing a user to a list of Books, you'll likely have a page somewhere called "Booklist.aspx" to which you'll direct him.  In that page, you'll have to provide everything needed to show that list.  This includes code for pulling data, applying any business logic, and displaying the results.  If there is any architectural or routing logic affecting the page, you'll have to code the architectural logic on the page as well.  *Good* Web Forms development usually involves the development of a set of supporting classes in a separate (unit-testable) DLL.  These class(es) will handle business logic, data access and architectural/routing decisions.

**MVC**

MVC takes a more "architectural" view of web application development: offering a standardized scaffold upon which to build.  It also provides tools for automatically generating model, view and controller classes within the established architecture.  For example, in both Ruby on Rails (just "Rails" from here on out) and ASP.NET MVC you'll always start out with a directory structure that reflects their overall model of web application architecture.  To add a view, model and controller, you'll use a command like Rails's "Rails script/generate scaffold {modelname}" (ASP.NET MVC offers similar commands in the IDE).  In the resulting controller class, there will be methods ("Actions") for Index (show list), Show, New and Edit and Destroy (at least in Rails, MVC is similar).  By default, these "Get" Actions just bundle up the Model and route to a corresponding view/html file in the "View/{modelname}" directory (note that there are also Create, Update and Destroy actions that handle a "Post" and route back to Index or Show).

The layout of directories and files is significant in MVC.  For example, in ASP.NET MVC, the *Index* method for a "Book" object will likely just have one line: "Return View();"  Through the magic of MVC, this will send the Book model to the "/View/Books/Index.aspx" page where you'll find code to display Books.  Rails's approach is similar although the logic is a bit more explicit and less "magic."  A *View* page in an MVC app is usually simpler than a Web Forms page because they don't have to worry as much about routing, business logic or data handling.

**Comparison**

The advantages of MVC revolve around a clean separation of concerns and a cleaner, more HTML/CSS/AJAX/Javascript-centric model for producing your output.  This enhances testability, provides a more standardized design and opens the door to a more "Web 2.0" type of web site.

However, there are some significant drawbacks as well.

First, while it is easy to get a demo site going, the overall architectural model has a significant learning curve.  When they say "Convention Over Configuration" it sounds good - until you realize that you have a book's-worth of convention to learn.  Furthermore, it is often a bit maddening to figure out what is going on because you *are* relying on magic rather than explicit calls.  For example, that "Return View();" call above? The exact same call can be found in other Actions but *they go to different places.* If you understand the *MVC convention* then you know why this is done. However, it certainly doesn't qualify as an example of good naming or easily understandable code and it is much harder for new developers to pick up than Web Forms (this isn't just opinion: I had a summer intern learn Web Forms last year and MVC this year and the differences in productivity were pronounced - in favor of Web Forms). BTW, Rails is a bit better in this regard although Ruby on Rails features dynamically-named methods that take some serious getting-used-to as well.

Second, MVC implicitly assumes that you are building a classic CRUD-style web site.  The architectural decisions and especially the code generators are all built to support this type of web application. If you are building a CRUD application and want to adopt a proven architecture (or simply dislike architecture design), then you should probably consider MVC. However, if you'll be doing more than CRUD and/or you are reasonably competent with architecture then MVC may feel like a straightjacket until you really master the underlying routing model (which is considerably more complex than simply routing in a WebForms app). Even then, I've felt like I was always fighting the model and worried about unexpected outcomes.

Third, if you [don't care for Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458802/doesnt-linq-to-sql-miss-the-point-arent-orm-mappers-subsonic-etc-sub-opti) (either because you are afraid that Linq-to-SQL is going to disappear or because you find Linq-to-Entities laughably over-produced and under powered) then you also don't want to walk this path since ASP.NET MVC scaffolding tools are build around Linq (this was the killer for me). Rails's data model is also quite clumsy compared to what you can achieve if you are experienced in SQL (and especially if you are well-versed in TSQL and stored procedures!).

Fourth, MVC proponents often point out that MVC views are closer in spirit to the HTML/CSS/AJAX model of the web.  For example, "HTML Helpers" - the little code calls in your vew page that swap in content and place it into HTML controls - are much easier to integrate with Javascript than Web Forms controls.  However, ASP.NET 4.0 introduces the ability to name your controls and thus largely eliminates this advantage.

Fifth, MVC purists often deride Viewstate.  In some cases, they are right to do so.  However, Viewstate can also be a great tool and a boon to productivity. By way of comparison, handling Viewstate is *much* easier than trying to integrate third-party web controls in an MVC app. While control integration may get easier for MVC, all of the current efforts that I've seen suffer from the need to build (somewhat grody) code to link these controls back to the view's Controller class (that is - to *work around* the MVC model).

**Conclusions**

I like MVC development in many ways (although I prefer Rails to ASP.NET MVC by a long shot).  I also think that it is important that we don't fall into the trap of thinking that ASP.NET MVC is an "anti-pattern" of ASP.NET Web Forms.  They are different but not completely alien and certainly there is room for both.

However, I prefer Web Forms development because, *for most tasks*, it is simply easier to get things done (the exception being generation of a set of CRUD forms). MVC also seems to suffer, to some extent, from an *excess of theory.*  Indeed, look at the many questions asked here on SO by people who know page-oriented ASP.NET but who are trying MVC.  Without exception, there is much gnashing of teeth as developers find that they can't do basic tasks without jumping through hoops or enduring a huge learning curve. *This* is what makes Web Forms superior to MVC in my book: MVC makes you pay a *real world price* in order to gain a bit more testability or, worse yet, to simply be seen as *cool* because you are using the *latest technology.*

Update: I've been criticized heavily in the comments section - some of it quite fair. Thus, I have spent several months learning Rails and ASP.NET MVC just to make sure I wasn't really missing out on the next big thing!  Of course, it also helps ensure that I provide a balanced and appropriate response to the question. You should know that the above response is a major rewrite of my initial answer in case the comments seem out of synch.

While I was looking more closely into MVC I thought, for a little while, that I'd end up with a major mea culpa. In the end I concluded that, while I think we need to spend a lot more energy on Web Forms architecture and testability, MVC really doesn't answer the call for me.  So, a hearty "thank you" to the folks that provided intelligent critiques of my initial answer.

As to those who saw this as a *religious battle* and who relentlessly engineered downvote floods, I don't understand why you bother (20+ down-votes within seconds of one another on multiple occasions is certainly not normal). If you are reading this answer and wondering if there is something truly "wrong" about my answer given that the score is far lower than some of the other answers, rest assured that it says more about a few people who disagree than the general sense of the community (overall, this one has been upvoted well over 100 times).

The fact is that many developers don't care for MVC and, indeed, this is not a minority view (even within MS as the blogs seem to indicate).

Comment: I agree with you. It seems like a great idea, done wrong. The zeal to get away from webforms threw away the best part of it.

Comment: Ruby on Rails is MVC. MVC is what Rails adds to Ruby. PHP has CakePHP which is MVC for PHP. There are other MVC frameworks for PHP as well, and overall they have already become a big deal. Smalltalk was just where the kernel of the concept started.

Comment: Ruby on Rails is not MVC in the fashion that smalltalk MVC was...True MVC wouldn't have all the logic in the controller.

Comment: MVC seems to be one of the most "open source" projects by MS to date - From what I've witnessed they are actively listening to the community, which in my opinion, is the best they can do.

Comment: As usual, you can get all the gory details on Wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller

Comment: I don't know that MVC fared so poorly.  The environment changed.  After Smalltalk, in early PC days, MVC abstractions were costly.  16-bit Windows apps still had memory management issues.  Web apps today are right back in the big-layered models, and MVC is a perfect abstraction.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the current way to develop webapps in Smalltalk: Seaside. DRY done right

Comment: Using the lack of use of SmallTalk to say MVC hasn't fared well is not the strongewst argument. The amount of interest generated by MVC over the last few years has been impressive, and has breathed new life into web development. The fact that Microsoft has taken notice undercores that.

Comment: I somewhat agree with your comment that it appears to be evolving without vision. (I don't agree with your incorrect use of "begs the question", though :), that means something entirely different than you think.)

Comment: Biggest advantages of MVC that I see are clear separation of concerns  and enhanced testability.  I don't think it's "based on theory" but rather based on market forces.  MVC (with TDD) makes it easier to rapidly write robust apps.  MS is competing with other langs that have MVC frameworks.

Comment: Great comments!  I guess it remains to be seen how well MVC does. I understand the appeal of a controller but there is something intuitively elegant about the consonance between document requests (the root of http) and dynamic document construction.  Maybe it is just me ;-).

Comment: -1, The original question is good - saying you don't understand why something is good and asking for more information is awesome. This answer, though, is very strange - you're basically stating "I don't understand either", but wrapping it in a story.

Comment: I find it interesting that your criticism of ASP.NET MVC is that it adds abstraction and overhead.  and therefore is more complicated.  It is precisely the opposite.  Webforms adds a layer of abstraction and MVC is far more straight forward and low-level that doesn't hide you from what you are doing

Comment: Your answer is uninformed. Just about every other platform (Smalltalk, PHP, Java, Ruby (Merb, RoR), Python (Django, Zope)) has been using MVC for *years* with great success. Even .net has had MVC for years with Monorail.

Comment: orip - where do I say "I don't understand either"?  That isn't true...I looked into MVC and felt that it didn't meet my needs.

Comment: Trevor - the web is built on a "document request" model.  In Webforms, the document being requested *is* the program.  This is clean and obvious. MVC adds the abstraction of the controller and then strips functionality to make the View simpler than a Webform.  I simply don't care for this approach.

Comment: maush: you make my point by pointing out Monorail. When MS introduced Webforms it exploded in popularity: growing very quickly and even stealing market share from Java (& thus MVC). But how many used Monorail? Essentially none. Also, PHP? Very little MVC till last year. PHP grew popular without it.

Comment: Folks, please don't get the idea that I am just bashing your favorite programming model. I'm not.  I am, however, enjoying learning from you all and doing research to respond to your points.

Comment: Why is this marked as "The answer" when the poster didn't even know anything about the MVC pattern when he answered?

Comment: ScottKoon - agreed, not sure why this was accepted. Seems that all he did was agree with the OP. -1

Comment: This isn't really that hard, guys.  I find the MVC model to be inferior to a page-based approach because it moves you away from a proven model (page request) that matches the page-oriented structure of the underlying web site.  I think I make this clear. The fact that you don't understand my rationale doesn't mean I don't understand MVC. The fact that you have managed to generate 15 downvotes in a few minutes just makes me sad that you lack meaningful things to do with your life.

Comment: -1. Honestly this is a very poor post. MVC has been in use on other platforms for years, has been proven solidly to work, and is just simply a better way of doing things except for the smallest or most bespoke sites.

Comment: Honestly, you haven't a clue or your couldn't possibly write that ASP.NET is only appropriate for the "smallest or most bespoke" sites.

Why do you think that, despite having several years head start, Java's popularity rapidly faded when MS brought out ASP.NET?  Is it still strong? Yes - after all people had years of sunk costs.  How has its growth compared to ASP.NET though?  Well, not very robust at all.  This is because the model is not very intuitive for the reasons I've described.

Comment: Just in case you doubt my assertions regarding ASP.NET's rapid rise to dominance over Java, you might want to check out: 

http://blogs.msdn.com/jonbox/archive/2008/06/22/net-and-java-growth.aspx 

and, for an older graph showing just when it happened: 

http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2004/03/23/aspnet_overtakes_jsp_and_java_servlets.html

Comment: As a young developer I've grown up on Java, C# and JavaScript and frankly I am not that fond of COM, however I have to disagree with your statement that the overall vision of COM is fundamentally flawed.

Based purelt on my (admittedly very limited) understanding of COM it's overall vision was to provide a means to facilitate communication between applications, and while the implementation cerainly does have it's negitive points I think in general COM has been succesful in achieving it's goal.

Comment: Smurf - thanks for your comments. My criticism of COM is focused on a number of points.  First, COM's original vision went well beyond interprocess communication and into the realm of composite applications (clicking a spreadsheet, for example, changed MS Word's menu to that of Excel).  This was a mistake on so many UI levels it is hard to know where to start. Second, even in the realm of interprocess comm there are far better ways to approach it - the implementation's suckage *is* the problem.

Comment: -continued-  But the most telling point is that the whole COM ediface was abandoned when Anders Hejlsberg left Borland to join Microsoft and kick off the .NET "rewrite," COM was jettisoned almost immediately. At this point, almost everyone who has had to do serious COM programming is damn glad the nightmare is over!

Comment: I take issue with your characterization of WebForms as better fitting the web paradigm.  WebForms is essentially the event-driven WinForms model overlaid on the web.  As such the framework -- and we developers if, heaven forbid, we attempt to do something with non-MS client-side tools -- has to jump through a lot of hoops to pretend that you're doing event-handling over the web.  MVC is a very natural fit for RESTful interfaces and REST attempts to put the web protocols to the use for which they were intended.   MS designed WebForms the way they did, not because it's the best fit for the web,

Comment: ...but because they could make it easy for WinForms programmers to make the transition.  Don't get me wrong.  I like C#/.NET but I always felt like I was fighting the framework to do what I wanted on the web.   WebServices, particularly ScriptServices, helped, but the real win comes with ASP.NET MVC.   It's a natural fit for the web precisely because it is loosely coupled and naturally mimics the loosely couple nature of web communications.  The fact that it has at least 50% more testable code than a comparable WebForms app is nothing to sneeze at either.

Comment: -1 for a horrible answer which is all "personal opinion" and none engineering.

Comment: Also, I read in the update that the SO staff has remove the down votes? If they were not from the same person with different newly created accounts then we censor the down votes?

Comment: SO automatically removes votes that are clearly driven by either BOTS or personal spite.  If another user goes through all of your answers and downvotes them just to spite you, the downvotes will be removed by the system automatically.

Comment: This is a *question* about programming style and whether something makes for good development practice.  That is, it is largely an *opinion* question. So, you shouldn't be surprised at the fact that my response was personal opinion.  What *I* am surprised about, foljs, is why so many people feel so strongly about MVC that they would put so much energy (and even rudeness) in an attempt to shout down someone who disagrees with them.

Comment: Based on my negative experiences with the ASP.NET page model I think the introduction of APS.NET MVC is great.  However I also think Mark has made some very good points, so I have upvoted his answer.  For all the downnvoters, just remember, Microsoft introduced ASP.NET MVC as an alternative to the Page model, not a replacement.  In my experience, more often then not, it is actually developer experience, skill and care (or lack of it) that creates good or bad web apps more so then the technology used.

Comment: I am also using asp.net from its beta.. Also did a lot with asp classic . I tried mvc from its initial versions . I am getting a feeling am i going back to asp classic ? I like webforms for rapid development.

Comment: I've seen that particular comment a lot.  The argument in *favor* of it is that is "gives you more control over the output." I understand the appeal (PageForms code can get ugly) but I don't understand why anyone would give up productivity to get pretty output when the ASPX / Code-behind is the actual code you work with - not the resulting output.  

The best argument in favor of MVC is improved testability. But I build my systems with a BL layer that already gives me that. The second-best is that Javascript coding is easier. ASP.NET 4, though, should ease that considerably.

Comment: This is strange, Complaining that the MVC framework is adding abstractions is simply wrong. You say "MVC incurs the overhead of a range of abstract dependencies in order to get something cool" and then later proclaim ASP.Net makes more sense/is less confusing/is better. But MVC reduces the abstractions and thus is easier for Web Developers from other platforms as it matches the way the web works (POST/Get/Stateless) which is not something that can be said of WebForms which was designed with WinForms programmers in mind and really does have a insane amount of abstractions

Comment: Damien - fair point...  The abstractions that I was speaking of concern control flow (routing via the controller).  But you are quite right about ASP.NET adding a variety of abstractions to make the page model work.  I doubt that I'll change this answer as it is kind of frozen in time now but I'm learning Ruby on Rails in order to get a closer handle on MVC development.  So far, I'm seeing things HBoss' was more and more...

Comment: That should be "HBoss' WAY more and more..."

Comment: Mark - MVC is much closer to how the web works than ASP.NET's page view.  Webforms is an abstraction to make things easier for Winforms (originally VB) developers.  Programmers who have done non-abstracted web programming get infuriated with webforms, simply because it tries to make it something that it is not - a stateful event-based page model.

Comment: Thanks Lucky - I appreciate the comment.  I'm looking into MVC at every opportunity but have a release to get out before I'll really be able to dig in.

Comment: referring to ruby on rails as "ruby" while referring to ASP.NET MVC as MVC is jarringly inconsistent.  ruby is a language, MVC is a framework.  It should be either ruby vs c#/vb or Rails vs MVC.

Comment: Peter - thanks for the comment.  I guess, instead of shortening "Ruby on Rails" to "Ruby", I could have shortened it to "Rails."

Comment: Lucky, I understand your point but, at the bottom, I have to disagree with you.  Now, you are right in the sense that the ViewState and the Sessions handling the come with WebForms make the web something other than the stateless document exchange format it was originally meant to be. But if you reread the point I was making, it concerned the "Controller" aspect of the MVC framework. 
Some years ago, I wrote a raw ISAPI dll for serving up "MDB" pages that was mildly popular in Delphi circles so I'm familiar with the low-level transactions that go on. At that time, I chose (continued)

Comment: I chose to map document requests directly to MDB documents - really small program modules - much as WebForms maps requests to the .aspx web forms.  This seems to me to be the most straightforward way in which WebForms "maps" to the underlying flow of calls that characterizes the web.  The Controller model in MVC, on the other hand, has essentially nothing in common with the web model. It is "closer to how the web works" only in the limited sense of not having as many tools to make application development easier.

Comment: But, with respect to the issue I was addressing (control) it simply isn't.

Comment: Well structured answer, I personally prefer ASP.NET MVC as i like to have control over my code and the output. Either way some good points raised.

Comment: WebForms is a horrible, leaky abstraction. If it didn't leak, the merits of it may be worth discussing. But the fact is, to do any non-trivial work with WebForms, you must understand the underlying architecture of the web. So, WebForms essentially fails as an abstraction. Why prop it up? If someone can write a tight, leak-proof abstraction of the way HTTP and HTML function, then you may be on to something, but right now that isn't the case. Why half-ass something? Personally, the half-assed approach of WebForms drives me nuts. When I have to use WebForms, I use many hacks just to keep sane!

Comment: So, even with my perspective on how to use WebForms, it is painful, but then when I have to maintain the code of someone that bought into everything Microsoft vomited-up for the WebForms model, I literally want to slit my wrists. Don't get me started about their Ajax solution either, what a bunch of utter CRAP. UpdatePanels?! Atrocity!!!

Comment: Jason - I answered your points in detail in the comments for HugoWare's answer below.  In short, I was very much a part of the community that struggled with creating a high-productivity web development environment in the early part of the decade; contributing code, articles and participating in many forum discussions in this community. You are simply wrong in your overall assertion that web forms was something "vomited up" by MS as part of some ill-considered "business strategy."  I appreciate that you don't like it and can even sympathize with some of your complaints, but still disagree.

Comment: 10 years later and you're still right :)

Answer (score 117):

MVC gives you more control over your output, and with that control comes greater risk of writing poorly designed HTML, tag soup, etc...

But at the same time, you have several new options you didn't have before...

1. More control over the page and the elements within the page
2. Less "junk" in your output, like the ViewState or excessively long IDs on elements *(don't get me wrong, I like the ViewState)*
3. Better ability to do client side programming with Javascript (Web 2.0 Applications anyone?)
4. Not just just MVC, but JsonResult is slick...

Now that's not to say that you can't do any of these things with WebForms, but MVC makes it easier.

I still use WebForms for when I need to quickly create a web application since I can take advantage of server controls, etc. WebForms hides all the details of input tags and submit buttons.

Both WebForms and MVC are capable of absolute garbage if you are careless. As always, careful planning and well thought out design will result in a quality application, regardless if it is MVC or WebForms.

**[Update]**

If it is any consolation as well, MVC is just a new, evolving technology from Microsoft. There has been many postings that WebForms will not only remain, but continue to be developed for...

[http://haacked.com](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/13/future-of-aspnet.aspx)

[http://www.misfitgeek.com](http://www.misfitgeek.com/Will+ASPNET+MVC+Be+The+Main+Web+UI+Platform+For+ASPNET.aspx)

[http://rachelappel.com](http://rachelappel.com/asp-net/asp-net-development-mvc-vs-web-forms/)

... and so on...

For those concerned about the route MVC is taking, I'd suggest giving "the guys" your feedback. They appear to be listening so far!

Comment: I think points 1 and 2 are the crux. Webforms as an abstraction just doesn't really "work" IMHO because it isn't an abstraction that maps well on top of what is really going on. I think ASP.NET MVC is a better fitting abstraction than webforms is given my limited experiecne with MVC.

Comment: And a lot of people use ASP.Net without touching MVC or Webforms.  I've seen lots of .Net applications that completely avoid the webforms model and just do everything in the code behind page.  And frankly, I think it works better.

Comment: Thanks for the update HBoss!  I'd hate to see MS abandon WebForms after spending 7 years working on them.

Comment: Daniel - you say Webforms doesn't "work" because it doesn't map well to the web model.  I respectfully disagree: http originated as a model for retrieving *documents*. The Webforms architecture simply extends the idea of documents so they are dynamic. This works for me...

Comment: @mdbritt. I respect your opinion because it is true on a high level of abstraction (retrieving a document). However, for me the psuedo statefulness and postback model is where it starts to break down, especially in highly dynamic scenarios. It works great for simple things, but it unravels quickly.

Comment: Um points 3 and 4 are the icing on the cake.  They're what make me want to flee from webforms.  Maintaining a gigantic (and growing!) webforms app and attempting to integrate javascript / Ajax can be ... not fun.  Integrating javascript / ajax (with JSON, no less) in MVC is practically a joy.

Comment: @Mark - It doesn't work well because it abstracts the real nature of the web far more than removing the URL --> Document relationship does.

Comment: "control comes greater risk of writing poorly designed HTML". I would disagree the HTML output from most standard ASP.NET controls are really poor. Confusing ID's (the have a semantic name, but move a control and the id change), table's from (I think) GridView is a mess, RadioButtonList makes no sense... etc.. This is where MVC gives you a great way of implementing proper HTML.

Comment: @Mark - "The Webforms architecture simply extends the idea of documents so they are dynamic." If that was all it did, maybe it would not be the pile of stinking poo that it is today (and was years ago). WebForms was nothing more than the result of MS trying to appeal to VB developers that were used to developing with their mouse instead of their keyboard. They wanted to bring all of those people along, make them feel loved, but at the same time created something far worse than anyone imagined. I am nearly convinced it was a business decision that drove it. MVC is superior by far.

Comment: @Mark - Curious as to how many hours you have logged doing non-trivial ASP.NET MVC work. Any? I ask because I want to see if you are ready to update your comparison and perhaps temper your strong pro-WebForms opinions...

Comment: @Jason - maybe you should tell us how you really feel... ;-)  With respect to my experience, I started writing pretty low-level ISAPI dlls that took a dynamic page definition (similar to how "aspx" pages are handled) and rendered html.  I have explored MVC in some detail but have not (to answer your question) written a full production system using the technology.  WRT whether ASP.NET was "nothing more" than trying to appeal to VB developers, we'll just have to disagree.  When MS built ASP.NET, the standard for fast-executing web pages was CGI/ISAPI. *Many* of their design decisions -continued-

Comment: spilled out of an attempt to simplify dynamic page generation with compiled code without needing explicitly external libraries. The forms handling was not just an attempt to "appeal to VB developers". Keep in mind that Anders Hjelsberg had just been lured away from Borland after the runaway success of Delphi and had been tasked with making remaking MS development via .NET.  So, WebForms *was* forms-based and clearly would appeal to VB developers - and Delphi developers, etc. etc. Forms-based development had proven to be wildly successful compared to Win32 so it is no surprise that -continued-

Comment: Microsoft thought that this would simplify web development as well. So - yes - WebForms is a leaky abstraction and is far from perfect. However, I think that you are ascribing motivations to Microsoft ("nearly convinced it was a business decision that drove it") that are simply not true.  I wasn't at Microsoft but I had met Anders, had contributed my ISAPI web tech to Borland (which won their 2000 programming contest in the Web category), wrote several dynamic web tech articles, and was very active in discussions of this topic in the years leading up to ASP.NET's release. -continued-

Comment: So...I was very much a part of this community in the early part of the decade and, while I appreciate your input, I can tell you that you simply don't have your history right.

Answer (score 76):

Most of the objections to ASP.NET MVC seems centered around the views, which are one of the most "optional" and modular bits in the architecture. [NVelocity](http://nvelocity.sourceforge.net/), [NHaml](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/), [Spark](http://sparkviewengine.com/), XSLT and other view engines can be [easily swapped out](http://www.coderjournal.com/2009/05/creating-your-first-mvc-viewengine/) (and it's been getting easier with every release). Many of those have MUCH more concise syntax for doing presentation logic and formatting, while still giving complete control over the emitted HTML.

Beyond that, nearly every criticism seems to come down to the <% %> tagging in the default views and how "ugly" it is. That opinion is often rooted in being used to the WebForms approach, which just moves most of the classic ASP ugliness into the code-behind file.

Even without doing code-behinds "wrong", you have things like OnItemDataBound in Repeaters, which is *just as* aesthetically ugly, if only in a different way, than "tag soup". A foreach loop can be much easier to read, even with variable embedding in the output of that loop, particularly if you come to MVC from other non-ASP.NET technologies. It takes much less Google-fu to understand the foreach loop than to figure out that the way to modify that one field in your repeater is to mess with OnItemDataBound (and the rat's nest of checking if it's the right element to be changed.

The biggest problem with ASP tag-soup-driven "spaghetti" was more about shoving things like database connections right in between the HTML.

That it happened to do so using <% %> is just a correlation with the spaghetti nature of classic ASP, not causation. If you keep your view logic to HTML/CSS/Javascript and the minimal logic necessary to do *presentation*, the rest is syntax.

When comparing a given bit of functionality to WebForms, make sure to include all of the designer-generated C#, and the code-behind C# along with the .aspx code to be sure that the MVC solution is really not, in fact, much simpler.

When combined with judicious use of partial views for repeatable bits of presentation logic, it really can be nice and elegant.

Personally, I wish much of the early tutorial content focused more on this end of things than nearly exclusively on the test-driven, inversion of control, etc. While that other stuff is what the experts object to, guys in the trenches are more likely to object to the "tag soup".

Regardless, this is a platform that is still in beta. Despite that, it's getting WAY more deployment and non-Microsoft developers building actual stuff with it than most Microsoft-beta technology. As such, the buzz tends to make it seem like it's further along than the infrastructure around it (documentation, guidance patterns, etc) is. It being genuinely usable at this point just amplifies that effect.

Comment: I did not know you could easily swap in other view engines, can you provide further info on that?

Comment: I don't have a link handy, but Phil Haack did an article a couple of weeks ago on his site showing how you can even run them side by side.

Comment: Amen! I hate using Findcontrol. I hate it so much.

Comment: Excellent, well rounded post.

Answer (score 59):

```
<% if (Model.PreviousPost || Model.NextPost) { %>
    <div class="pager">
        <% if (Model.PreviousPost) { %>
            <span><% Html.ActionLink("<< " + Model.PreviousPost.Subject, "view")); %></span>
        <% } if (Model.NextPost) { %>
            <span><% Html.ActionLink(Model.NextPost.Subject + " >>", "view")); %></span>
        <% } %>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

You can make another post asking how to do this without including the embeded CSS.

NOTE: ViewData.Model becomes Model in the next release.

And with the aid of a user control this would become

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Pager", Model.PagerData) %>
```

where PagerData is initialized via an anonymous constructor in the action handler.

edit: I'm curious what your WebForm implementation would look like for this problem.

Comment: Good post. The OP is missing out on some of the techniques such as reuse via RenderPartial that would make his code cleaner. In the OP's defense he did hint that he felt he must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 25):

I am not sure at what point people stopped caring about their code.

HTML is the most public display of your work, there are a LOT of developers out there who use notepad, notepad++, and other plain text editors to build a lot of websites.

MVC is about getting control back from web forms, working in a stateless environment, and implementing the Model View Controller design pattern without all the extra work that normally takes place in an implementation of this pattern.

If you want control, clean code, and to use MVC design patterns, this is for you, if you don't like working with markup, don't care about how malformed your markup gets, then use ASP.Net Web Forms.

If you don't like either, you are definitely going to be doing just about as much work in the markup.

**EDIT**
I Should also state that Web Forms and MVC have their place, I was in no way stating that one was better than the other, only that each MVC has the strength of regaining control over the markup.

Comment: I don't care about outputted markup (to a point), I care about maintainable code. The tradeoff here from Webforms is not worth it IMHO.

Comment: To elaborate, I've never had an issue with good markup from Webforms, sure you have a ViewState field, but if you are careful with your design, you don't get broken HTML.

Comment: When you see a 2mb Viewstate, have to do tons of control searching to find a control on a Web Form due to the naming malforming of the actual elements, something this light is welcomed.

I have always been anal about my code, anyone can View Source it, and I have OCD and want my house clean.

Comment: You only get a 2mb viewstate if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: You also get tag soup when you don't know what you're doing and throwing code together...

Comment: precisely, so posting this topic about how bad MVC is based on a poor coding sample is just about as bad as posting a Web Forms sample with a 2mb view state.  Its mis-using the tools due to poor knowledge.

Comment: @John- I'd say that doing anything in MVC after being in WebForms for so long is a little uncomfortable at the start, and even feels a little wrong at times. I think if you play with it more, you may see some of the advantages after a bit. For example,try doing some Ajax and see how much nicer it is

Comment: Tom - you make good points.  I investigated MVC because promised the isolation of data from depiction and, as you say, for cleaner, simpler HTML. Keep in mind that my response wasn't really based on  the code sample: I think I kept it at a higher level of abstraction than that!

Comment: Bah. Nonsense. WebForms is not what makes your markup *malformed*. Maybe the indentation and so forth is messed up .. big deal. If the code works well and is maintainable ... does it really matter how it is formatted when someone does a "view source?"

Comment: to people like me with OCD, yes.

Comment: @Tom Anderson ... then you are making an argument that it is bad not to have a disorder (Obsessive Compulsive Disorder). That seems pretty odd.

Comment: No, i am stating that for people WITH OCD, being able to use the power of ASP.Net and maintain control is great.

Answer (score 15):

I think you are missing some things.  First, there's no need for the Response.Write, you can use the `<%= %>` tags.  Second, you can write your own HtmlHelper extensions to do common actions.  Third, a little bit of formatting helps a lot.  Fourth, all of this would probably be stuck in a user control to be shared between several different views and thus the overall mark up in the main view is cleaner.

I'll grant you that the mark up is still not as neat as one would like, but it could be cleaned up considerably through the use of some temporary variables.

Now, that's not so bad and it would be even better if I didn't have to format it for SO.

```
 <%
    var PreviousPost = ViewData.Model.PreviousPost;
    var NextPost = ViewData.Model.NextPost;

    // Display the "Next and Previous" links
    if (PreviousPost != null || NextPost != null)
    {
  %>

 <div>

        <%= PreviousPost == null
                ? string.Empty
                : Html.ActionLinkSpan("<< " + PreviousPost.Subject,
                                "view",
                                new { id = PreviousPost.Id },
                                new { style = "float: left;" } ) %>
          <%= NextPost == null
                ? string.Empty
                : Html.ActionLinkSpan( NextPost.Subject + " >>",
                                   "view",
                                    new { id = NextPost.Id },
                                    new { style = "float: right;" } ) %>

  <div style="clear: both;" />
  </div>

  <% } %>
```

Comment: Doesn't it still seem just so strange, considering I could have just set the visibility of a <asp:hyperlink> in Webforms?

Comment: No, because even webforms wouldn't be that simple. You'd probably have to set some properties on the hyperlink in the codebehind because they're dynamic, you'd still need the DIV/span code, but you wouldn't be able to roll that into a method.  And none of it would be testable.

Comment: I've done enough webforms that the pain of dealing with databound controls and making them do what I want client-side, coupled with the ability to increase the amount of tested code at least 2-fold has won me over.  I've also done enough in Rails that this doesn't seem odd at all.

Comment: I'd have to set NavigateUrl, and Visibility. It would be 2 lines in the page_load event.

Comment: I think its the fact that you were doing this in rails. The last time I did this was classic ASP, which has a lot of other reasons to hate it.

Perhaps I just need to get over my initial gag reflex revulsion of <% %> tags.

Comment: @Jonathon : I submit to you that the code above is the same or fewer lines (though spread over more for SO) than your codebehind AND it's written in the same locality as the rest of the markup so I can see it all in one place.   I like not having to look elsewhere to see how my code will render.

Answer (score 14):

Please have a look at Rob Conery's post [I Spose I’ll Just Say It: You Should Learn MVC](http://rob.conery.io/2009/04/22/i-spose-ill-just-say-it-you-should-learn-mvc/)

Answer (score 13):

The big deal with MVC is that it's a conceptual framework that has been around a long time, and it has proven itself as a productive, powerful way to build both web applications and workstation applications that scale horizontally and vertically. It goes directly back to the Alto and Smalltalk. Microsoft is late to the party. What we have now with ASP.NET MVC is really primitive, because there's so much catching up to do; but damn, they're pouring out new releases fast and furiously.

What was the big deal with Ruby on Rails? Rails is MVC. Developers have been converting because, by word of mouth, it's become the way for programmers to be productive.

It's a huge deal; MVC and the implicit endorsement of jQuery are tipping points for Microsoft accepting that platform-neutral is critical. And what's neutral about it, is that unlike Web Forms, Microsoft can't lock you in conceptually. You can take all your C# code and reimplement in another language entirely (say PHP or java - you name it) because it's the MVC concept that's portable, not the code itself. (And think how huge it is that you can take your design and implement it as a workstation app with little code change, and no design change. Try that with Web Forms.)

Microsoft has decided that Web Forms will not be the next VB6.

Comment: Adding to that: There are a number of view-engines available that plug into MVC, including the default WebForms as well as a port of RoR's HAML (which bans angle brackets, especially when they include percent-signs).

Comment: Interesting way of stating it... Good points

Comment: HAML FTW, especially if your only objection to MVC is the <% %> 's

Answer (score 9):

The two main advantages of the ASP.NET MVC framework over web forms are:

1. **Testability** - The UI and events in web forms are next to impossible to test.  With ASP.NET MVC, unit testing controller actions and the views they render is easy.  This comes with a cost in up-front development cost, but studies have shown that this pays off in the long run when it comes time to refactor and maintain the app.
2. **Better control over rendered HTML** - You state that you don't care about the rendered HTML because nobody looks at it.  That's a valid complaint if that were the only reason to have properly formatted HTML.  There are numerous reasons for wanting properly formatted HTML including: SEO, the ability to use id selectors more often (in css and javascript), smaller page footprints due to lack of viewstate and ridiculously long ids (ctl00_etcetcetc).

Now, these reasons don't really make ASP.NET MVC any better or worse than web forms in a black-and-white sort of way.  ASP.NET MVC has its strengths and weaknesses, just like web forms.  However, the majority of complains about ASP.NET MVC seem to stem from a lack of understanding on how to use it rather than actual flaws in the framework.  The reason your code doesn't feel right or look right might be because you have several years of web forms experience under your belt and only 1-2 months of ASP.NET MVC experience.

The problem here isn't so much that ASP.NET MVC rocks or sucks, it's that it's new and there's very little agreement as to how to use it correctly.  ASP.NET MVC offers much more fine-grained control over what's occurring in your app.  That can make certain tasks easier or harder depending on how you approach them.

Answer (score 8):

Hey, I've been struggling with switching to MVC as well.  I am absolutely not a fan of classic ASP and MVC rendering reminds me a lot of those days.  However, the more I use MVC, the more it grows on me.  I am a webforms guy (as many are) and spent the past several years getting used to working with datagrids, etc.  With MVC that is taken away.  HTML Helper classes are the answer.

Just recently I spent 2 days trying to figure out the best way to add paging to a "grid" in MVC.  Now, with webforms I could whip this out in no time.  But I will say this... once I had the paging helper classes built for MVC, it became extremely simple to implement.  To me, even easier than webforms.

That being said, I think that MVC will be much more developer friendly when there are a consistent set of HTML Helpers out there.  I think we are going to start seeing a ton of HTML helper classes pop up on the web in the near future.

Comment: I would like to see your paging implementation because I have no idea how I'm going to tackle that one yet :)

Comment: Here's where I got the paging helpers from.  You can download the sample project here: http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/archive/2008/08/27/paging-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Comment: As with anything, there is a learning curve. You might be pleasantly surprised at how much better certain area's work. I won't lie though - some of the luxuries like Server Controls and ViewState are _certainly_ missed. I've typed in <asp:TextB... and then realized... Whoops!!

Comment: Here is an honest question.  If you need HTML "Helper" classes, haven't you really kind of violated the MVC model?  Aren't you leaving behind the simplicity and elegance with which it is sold?  If I'm wrong (and I may be!) please tell me why.

Comment: I don't think that you have to "switch" to MVC. I still use WebForms depending on the project.

Comment: @mdbritt - I feel the same way, for the most part the helper classes seem counter to the simplicity and transparency I would expect of MVC.

Comment: mdbritt & orbman, I was thinking the same thing as I loaded up all of the helpers.  To me, it seemed like a lot of code to generate paging.  I'm not sure if it's vilating the MVC model, but it does make it much simpler to read in the markup and to duplicate paging for other pages.

Comment: No, it doesn't violate the principle of MVC. Now, it might make you wonder if ASP.NET MVC is pointless but that is not really putting anything unecessary into your "view."

Comment: Helpers do not violate MVC.  It actually comes standard with built in helpers like: Html.TextBox.  And there are some projects that have popped up to aid in this... http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 8):

It's funny because that's what I said when I first saw webforms.

Comment: _Seriously_, it really was. WebForms, without knowing the context of the times that brought it to us, makes little sense. It doesn't embrace the web but tries to hide it, and it is a very poor abstraction.

Answer (score 6):

I'll admit that I don't get asp.net MVC yet.  I'm trying to use it in a side project I'm doing but it's going pretty slow.

Besides not being able to do things that were so easy to do in web forms I notice the tag soup.  It really does seem to take a step backwards from that perspective.  I keep hoping that as I learn it will get better.

So far I've noticed that the top reason to use MVC is to gain full control over your HTML.  I also read that asp.net MVC is able to serve up more pages faster than web forms and probably related to this, the individual page size is smaller than an average web forms page.

I really don't care what my HTML looks like as long as it works in the major browsers, but I do care how fast my pages load and how much bandwidth they take up.

Answer (score 6):

While I fully agree that that is ugly markup, I think using the ugly view syntax to write off ASP.NET MVC as a whole is not fair. The view syntax has gotten the least attention from Microsoft, and I am fully expecting something to be done about it soon.

Other answers have discussed the benefits of MVC as a whole, so I will focus on the view syntax:

The encouragement to use Html.ActionLink and other methods that generate HTML is a step in the wrong direction. This smacks of server controls, and, to me, is solving a problem that doesn't exist. If we are going to generate tags from code, then why bother using HTML at all? We can just use DOM or some other model and build up our content in the controller. Ok, that sounds bad, doesn't it? Oh yes, separation of concerns, that is why we have a view.

I think the correct direction is to make the view syntax as much like HTML as possible. Remember, a well designed MVC should not only give you separation of code from content, it should let you streamline your production by having people who are expert in layout work on the views (even though they do not know ASP.NET), and then later as a developer you can step in and make the view mockup actually dynamic. This can only be done if if the view syntax looks very much like HTML, so that the layout folks can use DreamWeaver or whatever the current popular layout tool is. You might be building dozens of sites at once, and need to scale in this way for efficiency of production. Let me give an example of how I could see the view "language" working:

```
<span mvc:if="ViewData.Model.ShowPrevious" style="float: left;">
    <a mvc:inner="ViewData.Model.PreviousPost.Subject" href="view/{ViewData.Model.PreviousPost.Id}">sample previous subject</a>
</span> 
<span mvc:if="ViewData.Model.ShowNext" style="float: left;">
    <a mvc:inner="ViewData.Model.NextPost.Subject" href="view/{ViewData.Model.NextPost.Id}">sample next subject</a>
</span> 
<div mvc:if="ViewData.Model.ShowNextOrPrevious" style="clear: both;" />
```

This has several advantages:

- looks better
- more concise
- no funky context switching betwen HTML and <% %> tags
- easy to understand keywords that are self-explanatory (even a non-programmer could do this - good for parallelization)
- as much logic moved back into controller (or model) as possible
- no generated HTML - again, this makes it very easy for someone to come in and know where to style something, without having to mess around with Html. methods
- the code has sample text in it that renders when you load the view as plain HTML in a browser (again, good for layout people)

So, what exactly does this syntax do?

mvc:inner="" - whatever is in the quotes gets evaluated and the inner HTML of the tag gets replaced with the resulting string. (Our sample text gets replaced)

mvc:outer="" -  whatever is in the quotes gets evaluated and the outer HTML of the tag gets replaced with the resulting string. (Again, sample text gets replaced.)

{} - this is used for inserting output inside of attributes, similar to <%= %>

mvc:if="" - insde the qoutes is the boolean expression to be evaulated. The close of the if is where the HTML tag gets closed.

mvc:else

mcv:elseif="" - ...

mvc:foreach

Comment: You could fairly easily implement exactly what you're describing as your own view engine and ditch the WebForms solution entirely.

Comment: i was going to make a note that there are other view engines available, and also that I think a cf-style markup would work well, which is what you are  showing here.

Comment: Thanks for the info, was not aware there were other view engines.

Comment: Genshi is a popular Python templating engine with a similar approach, you could look at it for more inspiration: http://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/GenshiTutorial#MakingtheApplicationDoStuff

Comment: But nobody liked XSLs so how do you expect this to get adopted?

Comment: I think the answer is by keeping the syntax/functionality ridiculously simple. You need something complicated, move it to the controller or model.

Comment: Remind me of Struts with JSTL and OGNL.  I do miss those things when coding ASP.MVC.

Answer (score 4):

Now, I can only speak for myself here:

IMO, if you're a die-hard (anything) then conversion isn't for you. If you love WebForms that's because you can accomplish what you need to, and that's the goal of any too.

Webforms does a good job of abstracting HTML from the *developer*. If that's your goal, stick with Web Forms. You have all the wonderful "click and drag" functionality that has made desktop development what it is today. There are many included controls (plus a wealth of third party controls) that can bring about different functionality. You can drag a "grid" that's directly associated with a DataSource from your database; it comes with built in inline-editing, paging, etc.

As of right now, ASP.NET MVC is very limited in terms of third party controls. So again, if you like Rapid Application Development, where a lot of functionality is wired up for you, you should not try to get converted.

With all of this said, this is where ASP.NET shines:
 - TDD. Code is not testable, nuff said.

- Separation of concerns. That is the backbone of the MVC pattern. I am fully aware that you can accomplish this in Web Forms. However, I like imposed structure. It was too easy in Web Forms to mix design and logic. ASP.NET MVC makes it easier for different members of a team to work on different sections of the application.
- Coming from somewhere else: My background is CakePHP and Ruby on Rails. So, it is clear where my bias lies. It's simply about what you're comfortable with.
- Learning Curve: To expand on the last point; I hated the idea of "templating" to change the functionality of different elements. I didn't like the fact that a lot of the design was accomplished in the code behind file. It was one more thing to learn, when I was already intimately familiar with HTML and CSS. If I want to do something in an "element" on the page, I stick in a "div" or "span", slap an ID on it and off I go. In Web Forms I would have to go research how to do this.
- Current State of Web "Design": Javascript libraries like jQuery are becoming more commonplace. The way that Web Forms mangles your IDs just makes implementation (outside of Visual Studio) more difficult.
- More Separation (Design): Because a lot of the design is wired into your controls, it would be very difficult for an outside designer (without Web Forms) knowledge to work on a Web Forms project. Web Forms was built to be the end all and be all.

Again, much of these reasons stem from my unfamiliarity with Web Forms. A Web Forms project (if designed right) can have "most" of the benefits of ASP.NET MVC. But that's the caveat: "If designed right". And that's just something I don't know how to do in Web Forms.

If you're doing stellar work in Web Forms, you're efficient and it works for you, that's where you should stay.

Basically, do a quick review on both (try to find a unbiased source [good luck]) with a list of pros and cons, evaluate which one fit your goals and pick based on that.

Bottom line, pick the path of least resistance and most benefit to meet your goals. Web Forms is a very mature framework and will only get better in the future. ASP.NET MVC is simply another alternative (to draw in Ruby on Rails and CakePHP developers such as myself :P )

Answer (score 3):

Java EE's JSPs looked like this when they were first proposed - ugly scriptlet code.

Then they offered up tag libraries to make them more HTML tag-ish.  The problem was that anybody could write a tag library.  Some of the results were disastrous, because people embedded a lot of logic (and even style) into tag libraries that generated HTML.

I think the best solution is the JSP Standard Tag Library (JSTL).  It's "standard", HTML tag-ish, and helps prevent people from putting logic into pages.

An added benefit is that it preserves that line of demarcation between web designers and developers.  The good sites that I see are designed by people with an aesthetic sense and designing for usability.  They lay out pages and CSS and pass them on to developers, who add in the dynamic data bits.  Speaking as a developer who lacks these gifts, I think we give something important away when we ask developers to write web pages from soup to nuts.  Flex and Silverlight will suffer from the same problem, because it's unlikely that designers will know JavaScript and AJAX well.

If .NET had a path similar to JSTL, I'd advise that they look into it.

Comment: +1 - more if I could give it.  Yeah... Java has been down this road long ago.

The weird part is that Java has also seen some MVC style frameworks that bolt on components as well - like JSF and Tapestry.

MVC is about the only sane architecture for a web application IMHO.  I wouldn't let beef with the framework prevent you from getting a deeper understanding of it.  The framework will evolve.

Answer (score 3):

Just thought I'd share how this sample looks with the shiny new [Razor view engine](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) which is default since ASP .NET MVC 3.

```
@{ 
    var prevPost = ViewData.Model.PreviousPost;
    var nextPost = ViewData.Model.NextPost;
}

@if (prevPost != null || nextPost != null) {
    <div>
        @if (prevPost != null) {
            <span style="float: left;">
                @Html.ActionLink("<< " + prevPost.Subject, "view", new { id = prevPost.Id })
            </span>
        }
        @if (nextPost != null) {
            <span style="float: left;">
                @Html.ActionLink(nextPost.Subject + " >>", "view", new { id = nextPost.Id })
            </span>
        }
        <div style="clear: both;" />
    </div>
}
```

Any problem with that?
Also, you shouldn't actually inline your CSS styles, should you? And why do you check for nullity in three places instead of just two? An extra `div` rarely hurts. This is how I'd do it:

```
<div>
    @if (prevPost != null) {
        @Html.ActionLink("<< " + prevPost.Subject, "view",
            new { id = prevPost.Id, @class = "prev-link" })
    }
    @if (nextPost != null) {
        @Html.ActionLink(nextPost.Subject + " >>", "view",
            new { id = nextPost.Id, @class = "next-link" })
    }
    <div class="clear" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak directly to the ASP.NET MVC project, but generally speaking MVC frameworks have come to dominate **web** application development because

1. They offer a formal separation between Database Operations,"Business Logic", and Presentation
2. They offer enough flexibility in the view to allow developers to tweak their HTML/CSS/Javascript to work in multiple browsers, **and future versions of those  browsers**

It's this last bit that's the important one.  With Webforms, and similar technologies, you're relying on your vendor to write your HTML/CSS/Javascript for you.  It's powerful stuff, but you have no guarantee that the current version of Webforms is going to work with the next generation of web browsers.

That's the power of the view.  You get full control over your application's HTML.  The downside is, **you** need to be disciplined enough to keep the logic in your views to a minimum, and keep the template code as simple as you possibly can.

So, that's the trade-off.  If Webforms are working for you and MVC isn't, then **keep using Webforms**

Comment: "you're relying on your vendor to write your HTML/CSS/Javascript for you" Thats nonsense. Does everyone use the prebuilt controls? We never have.

Comment: Point 1 is nonsense as well. Every app I've architected has been strongly separated, with just the code behind being binding logic for the view. The event handlers in teh codebehind simply called the appropriate methods in the business layer.

Comment: Like I said Jon, if Webforms is working for you and your shop has the time to develop their own controls, then keep doing it.

Comment: @FlySwat - you've NEVER used a DropDownList or DataGrid ?

Answer (score 2):

Most of my frustration with it is just not knowing how to do things "properly".  Since it was released as a preview we've all had a bit of time to look at things, but they've been changing quite a bit.  At first I was really frustrated but the framework seems workable enough to enable me to create extremely complex UI's (read: Javascript) pretty quickly.  I understand that you can do this with Webforms as I was doing it before but it was a huge pain in the butt trying to get everything to render correctly.  A lot of times I would end up using a repeater to control the exact output and would end up with a lot of the spaghetti mess that you have above as well.

In an effort to not have the same mess, I've been using a combination of having domain, service layers, and a dto to transfer to the view.  Put that together with spark, a view engine and it gets really nice.  It takes a bit to setup but once you get it going, I've seen a big step up in the complexity of my applications visually, but its so stinking simple to do code wise.

I wouldn't probably do it exactly like this but here's your example:

```
<if condition="myDtp.ShowPager">
  <div>
    <first />
    <last />
    <div style="clear: both;" />
  </div>
</if>
```

That's pretty maintainable, testable, and tastes yummy in my code soup.

The takeaway is that clean code is really possible, but it's a big ass shift from the way we were doing things.  I don't think everyone groks it yet though.  I know I'm still figuring it out...

Answer (score 2):

Steve Sanderson's recently published book 'Pro ASP.NET MVC' [1] [2] from Apress suggests another alternative -- creating a custom HtmlHelper extension.  His sample (from Chapter 4 on page 110) uses the example of a paged list, but it can easily be adapted for your situation.

```
public static string PostNavigator(this HtmlHelper html, Post previous, Post next, Func<int, string> pageUrl)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    if (previous != null || next != null)
    {
        result.Append("<div>");

        if (previous != null)
        {
            result.Append(@"<span class=""left"">");
            TagBuilder link = new TagBuilder("a");
            link.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(previous.Id));
            link.InnerHtml = String.Format("<< {0}", html.Encode(previous.Subject));
            result.Append(link.ToString());
            result.Append("</span>");
        }

        if (next != null)
        {
            if (previous != null)
            {
                result.Append(" ");
            }

            result.Append(@"<span class=""right"">");
            TagBuilder link = new TagBuilder("a");
            link.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(next.Id));
            link.InnerHtml = String.Format("{0} >>", html.Encode(next.Subject));
            result.Append(link.ToString());
            result.Append("</span>");
        }

        result.Append("</div>");
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

You would call it in your view with code something like this:

```
<%= Html.PostNavigator(ViewData.Model.PreviousPost, ViewData.Model.NextPost, id => Url.Action("View", new { postId = id })) %>
```

[1] http://blog.codeville.net/2009/04/29/now-published-pro-aspnet-mvc-framework-apress/

[2] http://books.google.com/books?id=Xb3a1xTSfZgC

Comment: Wow, thats horrible markup in code...Bleck.

Comment: If a 'PostNavigator' is a reusable widget (or WebControl if you will) with markup that doesn't change, and that is styled by CSS rules -- how is that such a horrible solution?

Comment: @GuyIncognito: Agreed, this seems analogous to a WebControl and a clean solution.  At some point, you have to generate a bunch of HTML strings.  An extension method like this is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Me too; I would spend my time on Silverlight rather than ASP.NET MVC.
I have tried MVC 1.0 and have had a look at the latest 2.0 Beta 1 release a few day ago.

I (can)'t feel that how ASP.NET MVC is better than webform.
The selling point of MVC are:

1. Unit (test)
2. Separate the design (view) and logic (controller + model)
3. No viewstate and better element id management
4. RESTful URL and more ...

But webform, by using code-behind.Theme, Skin, and Resource are already perfect to separate the design and logic.

Viewstate: client id management is coming on ASP.NET 4.0. I am only concerned about unit tests, but unit tests are not enough being a reason to turn me to ASP.NET MVC from webform.

Maybe I can say: ASP.NET MVC is not bad, but webform is already enough.

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping to see a post from Phil Haack, but it wasnt here so I just cut and paste it from 
http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/i-spose-ill-just-say-it-you-should-learn-mvc/ in the comments section

> Haacked - April 23, 2009 - Rob, you're a riot! :) I do find it funny when people write spaghetti code in MVC and then say "look! Spaghetti!" Hey, I can write spaghetti code in Web Forms too! I can write it in rails, PHP, Java, Javascript, but not Lisp. But only because I can't yet write anything in Lisp. And when I do write spaghetti code I don't look at my plate glumly expecting to see macaroni. The point people often make when comparing it to classic ASP is that with classic ASP people tended to mix concerns. Pages would have view logic with user input handling mixed in with model code and business logic all mixed up in one. That's what the spaghetti was about! Mixing concerns all in one big mess. With ASP.NET MVC, if you follow the pattern, you're less likely to do it. Yeah, you still might have a bit of code in your view, but hopefully that's all view code. The pattern encourages you to not put your user interaction code in there. Put it in the controller. Put your model code in a model class. There. No spaghetti. It's O-Toro Sushi now. :)

Answer (score -1):

I've been using MVC for since Preview 3 came out and while it is still has it's growing pains it helps quite a bit in the area of team development. Try having three people work on a single webforms page and then you'll understand the concept of banging your head on the wall. I can work with a developer who understands the design elements on the view page and our resident Linq god in making the model work while I put everything together in the controller. I've never been able to develop in a realm where the separation of concerns was so easy to achieve.

Biggest selling point of ASP.Net MVC - [StackOverflow runs on the MVC stack.](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=152)

That being said... your code is so much prettier than what I normally do with the view page. Also, one of the guys I work with is working on wrapping the HTML helper into a tag library. Instead of <%=Html.RandomFunctionHere() %> it works like

< hh:randomfunction / >

I just hope the MVC team gets around to it at some point because I'm sure they'd do a better job of it.

Comment: "...one of the guys I work with is working on wrapping the HTML helper into a tag library. Instead of <%=Html.RandomFunctionHere() %> it works like <hh:randomfunction />"

That's just it - a call to the method "RandomFunctionHere()" is just that - a method call. It is not markup, and abstracting that fact into something that _looks_ like a tag seems to me to be missing the point. If I am a developer looking at that code, I would rather see it as a method than some custom tag...

Answer (score -2):

Use a Facade Pattern to wrap all the logic for all the data you need to display and then use it as your generic in your view and then.... no more spaghetti code. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)

If you need more help cgardner2020@gmail.com

Answer (score -17):

The implementation ASP.NET MVC is horrible.  The product plain sucks.  I've seen several demos of it and I'm ashamed of MSFT...  I'm sure the guys who wrote it are smarter than me, but it's almost as if they don't know what the Model-View-Controller is.

The only people I know who are trying to implement MVC are people who like to try new things from MSFT.  In the demos I've seen, the presenter had an apologetic tone...

I'm a big fan of MSFT, but I have to say that I see no reason to bother with their implementation of MVC.  Either use Web Forms or use jquery for web development, don't choose this abomination.

**EDIT:**

The intent of the Model-View-Controller architectural design pattern is to separate your domain from the presentation from the business rules.  I've used the pattern successfully in every Web Forms project I've implemented. The ASP.NET MVC product does not lend itself well to the actual architectural design pattern.

Comment: Depending on the site, MVC is a very powerful tool out of the box without a lot of extra legwork.

For me, I am using just to get control BACK of my markup, the abomination that web forms can do to a simple website's markup is just... crazy.

Comment: I'd wager to say that MVC is actually quite good since it is being fit into the mold of ASP.NET, which is geared to favor WebForms...

Comment: @tom - if you have to preface a positive comment about something with... Depending on the site... you are already standing on thin ice.  I'll agree that if the requirement is to develop a site using ASP.NET MVC, that it may be a good choice, but for anything else, it looks like a bad choice.

Comment: @hboss - from the 'i'd wager' comment, i take it that you haven't actually seen how it works or tried to develop anything with it.

Comment: I use it all the time, Thanks - I like it quite a bit

Comment: @mson - not all sites should use MVC, it is very stated that this isn't the be-all end-all for ASP.Net development, Web Forms are still much more powerful in the end, but for site such as this one, it is a perfect fit for the pattern.

Comment: With every new product comes a slew of people who don't understand it, but instead of admitting such, give way to attacking it instead. Microsoft's MVC implementation takes a lot from existing implementations such as Rails and Monorail. That you don't understand the method doesn't make it suck.

Comment: MVC is still beta and it's an early implementation. The design is ok, but it's still maturing, especially with respect to default implementations of common controls. Eventually that will come, too. Hopefully, they'll make them easily extensible like HtmlHelper and unlike WebForms controls.

Comment: I've been extending (via subclassing) webform controls since day one, that seems much more pure than extension methods. MVC almost seems like an excuse to use all the new .NET 3.5 technologies for the sake of using them.

Comment: @mson, I think you are unfairly judging MVC based on one immature aspect (views) which have not yet been addressed.  The design and implementation of MVC is good, even though the implementaiton of the V part of MVC leaves a lot to be desired.  Views will get better.

Comment: @mson, as for not really following the MVC pattern, that is probably true. I'm worried that there is just too much ASP.NET MVC propaganda. It reminds me of more jibber jabber from the Agile people and those ALT.NET/NHibernate Mafia types.

Comment: I like, and prefer, chocolate to vanilla. Anyone want to argue with me about it?

Comment: @Jason CHOCOLATE IS HORRIBLE.  The product just plain SUCKS.... yru downvoting me?